# error in installation of cpp program

Tags: c++

I am trying to install a program that's built using CPP. Kindly provide suggestions for the following error.

```
pfm.cpp: In member function ‘void CPfm::read_pcm(std::ifstream&, bool):
pfm.cpp:539:29: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
       sid = mygetline(f,"ID");
                             ^
pfm.cpp:549:29: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
       sp0 = mygetline(f,"P0");
                             ^
```

Comment: Those are just warnings.

Answer (score 2):

It means `mygetline` takes a non-const `char*` argument, but you're passing it a pointer to a constant string literal. These days that's an error; but your compiler is using out-of-date rules, under which it's only deprecated, so you only get a warning.

If `mygetline` doesn't modify its string argument, then ideally you'd fix this by adding `const` to its declaration to enforce that. Then it's safe to pass a constant to it, as you're doing. Otherwise, you could ignore or disable the warning, and it won't be a problem until you update your compiler.

If it does modify its argument, so that making it `const` isn't an option, then you can't pass a string literal to it. You'll need a modifiable array, like

```
char bodge[] = "ID";
sid = mygetline(f,bodge);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is a constant string instead of a char pointer as the second argument of `mygetline`.
But it's just a warning not an error, the compiler seems to be ok with it.

Comment: I understand it is a warning but when I run the program I get this:Error in read_pcm: Cannot find line starting with ID.
Error in read_pcm: Cannot find line starting with P0.

Comment: That compiler might be OK with it, but a modern one wouldn't be, and neither would the program if the function tried to modify the string.

Comment: Here is the code:    void CPfm::read_pcm(ifstream &f,bool bsequences)
{
  //Search for the ID tag
  try
    {
      sid = mygetline(f,"ID");
      strim(sid);
    } catch (ELineNotFound) 
    {
      cerr << "Error in read_pcm: Cannot find line starting with ID.\n";
    }
  //Search for the P0 Tag
  string sp0;
  try
    {
      sp0 = mygetline(f,"P0");
    } catch (ELineNotFound) 
    {
      cerr << "Error in read_pcm: Cannot find line starting with P0.\n";
      exit(1);
    }

Comment: Hasn't warnings been as bad as errors? Not taking care of the warning can lead to undefined behavior later on.

Comment: I don't think anybody is saying warnings should be ignored, but rather concluding that - based on context - this particular warning is likely not the root cause of the problem (it is unlikely that the called function modifies the argument). The OP needs to do additional debugging.

Comment: @AndrewMedico You summarized well. Of course warnings shouldn't be ignored as they can cause unexpected runtime errors. But in the OP's case it's not the warnings that prevent the program to compile.